# Let $A^T = A$, find $\mathcal{F}^\pm e^{-\langle Ax, x\rangle}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

> Let $A^T = A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\langle Ax,x\rangle \geqslant \alpha \|x\|^2$ for a certain fixed $\alpha>0$.
>   Prove:
>
> 1) $e^{-\langle Ax,x\rangle} \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$
>
> 2) Find $\mathcal{F}^\pm e^{-\langle Ax, x\rangle}$.
>
> Hint: $A$ is  orthogonally diagonalizable.

I have proved the first part but how should I tackle the second problem:

$$\mathcal{F}^\pm e^{-\langle Ax, x\rangle}(y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac{n}{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{\pm i \langle x,y\rangle}e^{-\langle Ax, x\rangle}\operatorname d x$$
$$= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac{n}{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{\pm i \langle x,y\rangle-\langle Ax, x\rangle}\operatorname d x$$

I don't see how I could use the hint, orthogonally diagonalizable means $\exists P, P^T= P^{-1}$ such that $PAP^T$ is a diagonal matrix containing all the eigenvalues?

### Edit

I have found (under the same conditions) the following in a different text. But how do I prove this?

$$\mathcal{F}^- (e^{-\langle Ax, x\rangle})(y) = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}\sqrt{\det A}}e^{-\frac{1}{4}\langle A^{-1}y,y\rangle}$$

I find this a bit weird, $\det{A}$ suggests it is some sort of Jacobian.

But besides that, $A^T=A$ doesn't imply invertibility? Why would $\langle A^{-1}y,y\rangle$ even exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some sleep, thinking and scribbling I found the solution:

First note how $\langle Ax,x\rangle = \langle PDP^Tx,x\rangle = \langle Dx,x\rangle$ since $\langle PDP^Tx,x\rangle = \langle DP^Tx,P^Tx\rangle = \langle Dx, PP^Tx\rangle$

Then all I needed to to is write this $\langle Ax,x\rangle$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i x_i^2$ and $\langle x,y\rangle$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$ then:

$$=C\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-i x_iy_i - \lambda_i x_i^2} \operatorname d x_i$$ where after some variable substitution it yielded the answer as requested.

In retrospect a pretty fun exercise :)

Comment: I don't see why $\langle DP^T x,P^Tx \rangle = \langle D x,PP^Tx \rangle$.

Comment: Note how $DP^T = P^TD$ since $D$ is a diagonal matrix, then $\langle P^TD x, P^T x\rangle = \langle Dx , P P^T x\rangle$

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer to the question why $A^{-1}$ exists:

From $\langle Ax,x\rangle \geq \alpha \|x\|^2$, we can indeed deduce invertibility. One way to see this is via the numerical range, which in this case is contained in the interval $[\alpha, \infty)$, thus the spectrum needs to be in this interval, too. Hence, $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

But we can see this directly, too: Suppose $Ax=0$. Then we have:

$$0 \leq\alpha\|x\|^2\leq\langle Ax,x\rangle \leq \|Ax\|\|x\|=0\cdot\|x\|=0,$$

thus $x=0$, hence $A$ is injective. For a square matrix, this means it's bijective and hence invertible. If $A$ would be an operator, one would be able show that $A$ is surjective by hand as well.